i tried to do facade pattern and its not working
I am new to Springboot and i am now currently trying to learn how to use it with facade pattern. What is the main thing to do in facade and why should i use it. I tried to do it but i am not getting it right at this moment.this is the code i did by trying to find a adrress by a city id.im just posting the code im having trouble with
this is the repository class
@Repository
public interface EmployeeAddressRepository {
        List<EmployeeAddress> findAllByAddress_City_Id(String cityid);
}

service class
@Service
public class EmployeeAddressService {
    private EmployeeAddressRepository repository;
    public List<EmployeeAddress> getallempbycityid(String cityid){
        return this.repository.findAllByAddress_City_Id(cityid);
    }
}

@Component
public class EmployeeAddressApi {
    private EmployeeAddressService employeeAddressService;
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    @Autowired
    EmployeeAddressApi(EmployeeAddressService employeeAddress, EmployeeService employee) {
        this.employeeService = employee;
        this.employeeAddressService = employeeAddress;
    }
    public List<EmployeeAddress> getEmployeebycityId(String cityId) {
        List<EmployeeAddress> EMPADDRESSLIST = employeeAddressService.getallempbycityid(cityId);
        //adding names and emp id in list
        List<Name> namesList = new LinkedList<>();
        //sorting and getting just names
        for (EmployeeAddress ea : EMPADDRESSLIST) {
            namesList.add(employeeService.findById(ea.getStaffId()).getName())
        }
        if (namesList.isEmpty())
            return null;
        List<String> surnames=new ArrayList<>();
        for(Name n:namesList){
            surnames.add(n.getLastName)
        }
        //return surname
            return namesList;
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employeeaddress")
public class EmployeeAddressController {
    private EmployeeAddressApi employeeAddressApi;

    EmployeeAddressController(EmployeeAddressApi employeeAddressApi){
        this.employeeAddressApi=employeeAddressApi;
    }
    @GetMapping("/getempbycityid/{cityId}")
    public List<Name> read(@PathVariable String cityId){
        return employeeAddressApi.getEmployeebycityId(cityId)};
}
//testController
@Test
d b_read() {
    String cityid="cityid"
    String url=base_url+"/read/"+cityid;
    System.out.println("URL"+ url);
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders=new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<String> entity=new HttpEntity<>(null,httpHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<String> response=restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,entity,String.class);
    assertNotNull(response);
    System.out.println("allcity"+cityid;
    System.out.println("getall"+response.body();
}

I am trying to get a adress by a cityId then from that get a employee last name from the city id

Where's the jQuery in this question. The tag seems inappropriate.

Assuming you are talking about facade pattern utilized by JPA, we use JPA to make our life easier. We can use JPA in our code and make queries to the databases easily without actually writing the query ourselves because JPA provides us predefined methods for querying our required values. Now some points I would like to make about your code which seems faulty are -

You haven't implemented JpaRepository in your repository class. You need to do that first in order to declare your repository as a JPA repository and use its functionality.
In case you haven't added JPA dependency, please do add spring-boot-starter-data-jpa in your pom.xml.
I cannot see your entity class here, in case you have an entity class do add in your question.
For service class, please create a service interface first and then implement it in your service class.
In your EmployeeAddressApi class, you have added autowired to your constructor injection itself. There is no need for that. Either use autowired or constructor injection only. Tip: If you are using eclipse, declare your private variable and then right click on it -> Source -> Generate Constructor using fields.

Please try these changes and update your question as well for clarity.
In case you still have doubts regarding what JPA is, which I am assuming you will have, do go through the JPA documentation. Everything about JPA that you need to know is explained there thoroughly, do give it a read!
JPA doc
